# How to write the selenium code for scroll down the mouse action, I will try with this below code it was

Tags: java, selenium

How to write the selenium code for Scroll down the mouse below. I try to use the below code it was not scrolling action.

```
JavascriptExecutor Scrool = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
Scrool.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", ""); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: JavascriptExecutor Scrool = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     Scrool.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: I was try the above mentioned code

Comment: there is an "edit" button right below your question to add all the relevant information directly into it

Answer (score 0):

use this method. Call this method with actual webelement where you would like to scroll

public void scrollToElement(WebElement element) {
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
 }

Comment: void is an invalid type for the variable scrollToElement
 Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/button[2]/span[1]/svg/path
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-9J711O9', ip: '10.1.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.2'

Comment: so looks like the problem in your absolute XPath. show the website and web element which you are trying to scroll and maybe I can send you ready code. or try to delete '/SVG/path' at the end of your web element maybe because of it failing with no such element exception

Comment: @tester
String xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/button[2]/span[1]";

public static void scrollToElement(WebElement element) { ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element); }

so you just need to call this method with your xpath which i copy pasted from your error message. 

scrollToElement(xpath);

Comment: p.s. i am blind, i have no idea where you copy paste your code.to which webElement you are trying to scroll. if its not gonna solve your problem, take a screenshot of website, and your code and share with me so i can help you

Comment: https://www.abservetechdemo.com/products/rebueats/    ----> this is our website

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("scrollBy(0,2500)");  
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: @tester but you are using implicit wait, after scrolling. use it before scrolling and use my method which i sent to you. 
to which web element are you trying to scroll?

Comment: @tester i added a new comment to your post i found the issue. so follow steps on new comment and i am sure you will get success

Comment: @tester
i post it like a new comment you can check it. but here is the code also:
driver.get("https://www.abservetechdemo.com/products/rebueats/");
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("scrollBy(0,2500)");

Answer (score 0):

@tester 
so, first of all, you need to be careful with automation. Before to start the automation check website and be sure that there are no iframes. in your case on your website, you have IFRAME that's why you are getting no such element exception which means your code not reaching this web element.

so to handle this problem you can run it in 2 ways. 
the first way to scroll to webelement which you need

```
driver.get("https://www.abservetechdemo.com/products/rebueats/");
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    WebElement scrollToelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //h2[contains(text(),'Your restaurant, delivered')]"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", scrollToelement);
```

and the second way just uses your own code but add this driver.switchTo.iframe(0). in your case, you have only 1 iframe so 0 means index of the iframe.

```
driver.get("https://www.abservetechdemo.com/products/rebueats/");
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("scrollBy(0,2500)");
```

I am sure this will solve your issue I test it couple times